# How do I get the “Jar of Souls” and "Matriarch's Bones" achievements?

Tags: diablo-iii

I cleared the beta (killed the Skeleton King) twice with my Demon Hunter, and didn't get either of these achievements.

I've searched in the open map and cathedral. Is it in a crypt?

Where can I go to get these events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Jar of Souls is **in one of the two false (one-level) Defiled Crypts in the cemetery**. At least one will have the "[Jar of Souls](http://www.diablowiki.com/Jar_of_Souls)" **or** "[Matriarch's Bones](http://www.diablowiki.com/The_Matriarch%27s_Bones)" Event quest (though it's impossible to predict which). A handy trick: leave the game if you have the wrong one, as the event could reset to the Jar instead.

You'll enter a room with a blue jar and enemies will attack you for a minute. Then it'll pop.

Comment: There is 3 Defiled Crypts in the cemetery. *1-* is the real one (with second floor). *2-* have one of the two quests, these are random. *3-* is just a normal crypt with monsters.

Comment: I've read that between the two fake ones, at least one _must_ have the Event quest, though it's possible to get both (one in each).

Comment: I am running as a group looking for the quest Jar. I cleared all 3 chambers 13 times (at the moment). I didn't found the Jar yet (I believe it's 5% or 10% chance to find this quest instead of the "Matriarch's Bones"). In none of the tries I got both quest (as you could already have noticed)

Comment: @Michel ...What. I was going to ask about The Matriarch's Bones because I've never, ever received that quest and I'm one of those people who will get the Thorough Inspection achievement without even trying. I've played through about a dozen+ times and have always received the Jar of Souls.

Comment: @FAE I edited my question to fit the Matriarch's Bones too.

Answer (score 2):

Diablo is known for its random quest generation. There is no guarantee that you will have the opportunity to obtain the quest on a given playthrough.

With that said, if it appears, it is in one of the incorrect Defiled Crypts in the Cemetery of the Forsaken.

Comment: I Agree with the point that Diablo generate random maps, but the itens are always in the same points (Cain is inside the catedral for example, he will never be out in a cave). There are 3 Defiled Crypts 1 have the 2 floor, so I am looking for another between the 2 left, or this Jar stay inside the 2 floor one?

Comment: It will be in one of the other two (if it appears at all...)

Comment: So it's in one of the 2 left. OK. But it's **also** random in term if it will or will not appears at all, is that right?

Comment: I believe so, yes. I stand to be corrected on that.