# Are there unique hardcore quests in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I had the chance to play one hardcore character in Diablo 3, and I found a quest in the crypts that I haven't been able to find with normal characters. Are there quests unique to hardcore characters in Diablo 3 or are some quests simply very rare encounters?

Comment: related [How do I get the “Jar of Souls” and “Matriarch's Bones” achievements?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63582/how-do-i-get-the-jar-of-souls-and-matriarchs-bones-achievements)

Comment: Not related, I'm not asking how to get those quests so much as I'm asking if it's *always* possible to get them. I.e. is there a difference between hardcore and normal quest availability.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're talking about the [Jar of Souls](http://www.diablowiki.com/Jar_of_Souls) or [Matriarch's Bones](http://www.diablowiki.com/The_Matriarch%27s_Bones) quests that randomly appear in one of the incorrect defiled crypts, then no. These quests are simply random and can appear on any difficulty or hardcore setting.

It remains to be seen for the rest of the game, I don't know of any specific answers that have been given out by Blizzard staff mentioning hardcore-specific quests.

Comment: I found this to be the case as well. I think they are giving you a consolation for being in the wrong crypt / an incentive to search the other crypts even after you find the right one.

Comment: @JamesCW They've got some great incentives for not just rushing bosses like in D2, this is one of them.