# Chance of finding random events?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have seen several questions regarding *where* to find the random events (such as [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66068/are-there-unique-hardcore-quests-in-diablo-3) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69470/diablo-3-side-quests-list)), but I was wondering what is the *chance* of finding a random event?

I seem to find the "Jar of Souls" event all the time, but I have not seen the "Matriarchs Bones" event at all.  Does each event have its own chance of appearing (event X has 15% chance, event Y has a 20% chance)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the same chance to take a 20 in a dice.

Answer (score 1):

Events (as well as random dungeons) have a percentage chance to appear per game. Some, like the Jar of Souls, are more common than others. I do not believe that there is a full listing of percentage chances per event or dungeon compiled at this time.