# What random events are possible in the false crypts?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I have played through the crypts a few times and I have run across [two events](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63582/how-do-i-get-the-jar-of-souls-and-matriarchs-bones-achievements) so far, an endless wave of skeletons that you have to survive and recovering bones for a ghost. Are there any other events here? These two seemed to come with their own achievements which is why I am wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other events in the crypts.

You can see a discussion [here](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?821974-Mysterious-Defiled-Crypt-Events-D3-Beta) and also [on the wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Defiled_Crypt) those are the only two reported.

Comment: Ah well, disappointing but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an event where you go into the dungeon, and there are mobs named after game developers/producers/etc. and you have to kill the Game Developer Jay who is an elite unburied. This is a feat of strength achievement I've done on Nightmare difficulty.

Comment: Do they appear within the crypts in the graveyard though?

Comment: @James yes - see my post here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69875/how-is-the-quality-well-in-old-tristram-unlocked regarding developer hell. It is a completely separate crypt that can spawn in the same area but it is not an "event" as such, more an easter egg with a feat of strength.