# Where is the "Jar of Souls" event in Act 1?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the “Jar of Souls” and “Matriarch's Bones” achievements?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63582/how-do-i-get-the-jar-of-souls-and-matriarchs-bones-achievements)

In Diablo 3, where can we find the "Jar of Souls" event in Act 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jar of Souls can be found in the Defiled Crypts beneath the Cemetary of the Forsaken.

Taken directly from the wiki:

In each game there are four possible locations for tomb entrances below the Cemetery of the Forsaken. Three of them are randomly-activated each game, and those three entrances randomly access the following four levels:

- One small tomb with no special events inside.
- One medium-sized tomb with a stairway down to a lower level, which leads down to the Shattered Crown item.
- One large tomb in which players will find either the Jar of Souls event or the Matriarch's Bones event, but never both.
- [The Development Hell Level](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67860/8462)

[Source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Jar_of_Souls)

Answer (score 0):

It's randomly found in one of the tombs as you're searching for Leoric's crown, in about 50% of games.

You'll either find the "Jar of Souls" event or the "Matriarch's Bones" event in every game, if you search all three tombs thoroughly.

It's been said that you can also (rarely) get both, though I've never verified that to be true myself.

Answer (score 0):

The Crypts in the Cemetary of the Forsaken have a random chance of spawning the Jar of Souls event

If the event is there, it is almost always in the very center of the map, with paths going in each of the 4 directions, so it's typically easy to tell fairly fast if the event is there or not